# In solid state physics and Density Functional Theory, how are Van Der Waals forces modelled?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, density-functional-theory

Given a material, I'd like to know how to treat VdW interactions among layers. Specifically I'm using Quantum Espresso, an open-source suite based on Density Functional Theory, and I'd like to know how VdW forces are implemented in the Kohn-Sham equation. Does it insert $$ V \propto \frac{1}{r^6} $$ in the effective potential?

Comment: I guess [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) is the better place to ask.

Comment: $\sim r^{-6}$ interaction comes from perturbation theory from dipole-dipole interactions, so my naive guess is that it is more tricky than simle insertion. You can read https://doi.org/10.1021/ct900699r as introduction to subject and also check https://manual.q-chem.com/5.2/Ch5.S7.html